# Error installing VLC on Mint

Tags: apt, vlc

I've been trying to install VLC on Xenial, should be pretty easy, but then again I only halfway know what I'm doing:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I get a package error every time. I've tried doing the same using Synaptic, same problem. It can't install a particular package. I've narrowed it down, and this is the problem package:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-ffmpeg56
```

and I get the following error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavformat-ffmpeg56
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 444 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/806 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,157 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 228887 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libavformat-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libavformat-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56.40.101' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56.40.101.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libavformat-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now of course other errors may present themselves after this gets resolved, but I just don't know if there is a missing or corrupted package.

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no (official) flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a corruption in the file it's trying to install, you can tell because of this error: `lzma error: compressed data is corrupt`

This can be caused by a bad connection, resumed download, bad file, disk corruption or failures etc.

The problem you have is that it has kept the file, and instead of downloading a fresh copy it's trying to install the cached version.

Dothis:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo rm libavformat-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Alternatively, you could do a `sudo apt-get autoclean` to clear your cached packages.

This should delete the version that is causing problems and allow your PC to download a fresh copy.

Comment: `autoclean` didn't work, but manually removing the downloaded package did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @mherzig - Excellent! Great to hear :)